# Lua multithreading performance decreased

Tags: lua

## **The test environment**

Platform: Window64 16-core I7-8700 3.2ghz

To crash the process, I created a luaVM for each thread, and each VM ran its own data separately.

Lua time increases as the number of threads increases, decreasing by 10% to 50%,

the memory allock 8byte ~ 1024byte 200thousand count，among 256~1024 allock 100thousand count.

so Use Jemalloc or a custom memory allocator [skynet](https://github.com/wyuelin/skynet/commit/40281a8853a885428f3c2420ee6fc78718868d83) to replace the system's own memory allocator to avoid multithreading , but it didn't reduce run time

why？ What should I do？

Comment: The more CPU threads are active the slower each one runs.  This is because they share common CPU cache.

Comment: Each thread has a separate VM and memory allocator， 
in theory, there will be no false share

Comment: i7-8700 has 12 MB Intel® Smart Cache (a cache memory shared between all the cores)

Comment: I used affinity to lock the CPU for each thread, but the performance was only marginally better